# Remove special characters using gsub

Tags: r

How can someone remove this expressions – ( in gsub

Command:

```
gsub("– (", "", df$Names)
```

Error:

```
Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\("
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis character `(` with a double backslash - one for `gsub` and one for `R`:

```
gsub("– \\(", "", df$Names)
```